# GNOME login screen shows deleted user's workspace

Tags: centos, gnome, kvm

I am running a CentOS 7 VM on Linux Mint via KVM for study purposes. Ever since I created then deleted a regular user on the VM, its GNOME login screen always flashes a screenshot of the **deleted** user's workspace, before presenting the normal login screen. Is it a bug for the GNOME?

Comment: Isn't that workspace just equal to any new user workspace? How do you know it's related to that user specifically?

Comment: @Zip The flash image was a screenshot containing an open Terminal window showing the deleted user name in the shell prompt. It was apparently captured while I was configuring SELinux under the deleted user account. Now the problem is gone after I created a couple of new VMs. Not sure what caused that though.

Comment: I have a similar issue on my desktop which I suppose is related to some framebuffer garbage left somewhere that, when you're on the login screen ends up being shown as background until the correct data is put on the screen. What's weird to me is that it got written to disk somehow (otherwise it wouldn't survive a reboot). Is your video card an nvidia with the nouveau drivers by any chance?

Comment: @Zip Sorry for getting back lately. You seems having the exact issue as I had experienced. As you said the screenshot must have been captured and stored on disk to survive a reboot not only on the VM but on the host machine too. As for the video card, I am using the onboard video card on an Intel H67 chipset motherboard. No dedicated video card is installed.